# Is there a map that shows Austrian winter road closures?

Tags: driving, automobiles, road-trips, austria, winter

Some highways in Austria close for the winter season.  For example, the [Grossglockner High Alpine Road](http://www.grossglockner.at/en/) is closed until sometime in May.

Where can I find a map that shows which roads are currently open/closed?

Answer (score 8):

The information you're looking for is which mountain passes are open/closed. [Here's a site](http://www.alpenpaesse.co/) (in German) detailing the situation in Austria, as well as Germany, France, Italy, Switzerland and Slovenia. Purple/red means that the passes are closed.